Difference between MSVC and GCC/Clang for constexpr constructor
EDIT:  this was a compiler issue and has now been resolved by Microsoft.  Refer to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-compiler-regression-constexpr-constr/10677725.
I would please like some help understanding why the following code does not compile in MSVC (/std:c++20) but does in GCC and Clang.  Seems to be related to the constexpr constructor maybe.
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
    
    
class TestX
{
    bool GetA(char * outVal, unsigned int outValLen) {(void)outVal, (void)outValLen; return false;}

    struct SupportedParam
    {
        using GetParamFunc = bool (TestX::*)(char * outVal, unsigned int outValLen);
        constexpr SupportedParam(GetParamFunc gp) : GetParam(gp) {}
        GetParamFunc GetParam;
    };
    
    static const auto & SupportedParameters()
    {
        static constexpr std::array<SupportedParam,1> t =  
        {
            SupportedParam(&TestX::GetA)
        };
        static_assert(t[0].GetParam == &TestX::GetA);
        return t; 
    };
    
public:
    
    void Print()
    {
        for(auto & x : SupportedParameters())
        {
            std::cout << (this->*x.GetParam)(nullptr, 0);
        }
    }
};
    
    
int main(void)
{
    TestX x;
    x.Print();
}


Always post complete error along with your question.

It seems like a bug introduced in the recent MSVCs (assuming gcc and clang are correct). It compiles OK up to MSVC 19.35, but not in later versions. See demo.

As a workaround, just define SupportedParameters out of class as shown in this answer.

This seems to be a regression/bug in the latest msvc version starting from 19.36.
As a workaround you could define SupportedParameters outside TestX as shown below:
class TestX
{
//other code as before

//this is a declaration
static const std::array<SupportedParam,1>&  SupportedParameters();
public:

//other code as before 
}; 
//out of class definition workaround
const std::array<TestX::SupportedParam,1>&  TestX::SupportedParameters()
{
     static constexpr std::array<SupportedParam,1> t =  
    {
        SupportedParam(&TestX::GetA)
    };
    static_assert(t[0].GetParam == &TestX::GetA);
    return t;
} 

Working demo

Nice job finding a valid workaround.

@wohlstad Thanks. I tried finding a dupe but couldn't find that mentions this bug. In case you find any, let me know I'll close and then delete this answer.

the chances of me finding a dupe that you haven't are infinitesimal ;-)

@wohlstad Haha, good one :)

Thanks for narrowing in on the compiler version.  I went a bit further and tested Visual Studio 17.2.6 which compiles OK and 17.10.1 which does not.  So the compiler change was made between those versions.  I have not compiled this code for a long time and have updated Visual Studio since, but it was long enough ago that I never even remembered!

This has now been resolved by Microsoft.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-compiler-regression-constexpr-constr/10677725
